# rethinkdb-elixir client: Filter based on the presence of a value in an array

Tags: elixir, rethinkdb

Given example documents in a RethinkDB like the following

```
[{id: "1", tags: ["alpha", "bravo", "charlie"]},
{id: "2", tags: ["delta", "echo", "foxtrot"]}]
```

I know I can easily filter in the tags array using the RethinkDB data explorer like so:

```
r.db("mydb").table("mytable").filter(r.row("tags").contains("delta"));
```

However, I'm getting stuck when trying to use the rethinkdb-elixir client. I thought that the following would retrieve it:

```
q = Query.table("mytable")
q = Query.filter(q, %{tags: Query.contains(q, "delta")})
```

I then thought maybe a function would work like so:

```
q = Query.filter(q, lambda fn (doc) ->
  # ???
end)
```

but I seem to have encountered a dead end at this point.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Much thanks to the main contributor to the rethinkdb-elixir repo for providing an answer:

```
q = Query.filter(q, lambda fn (doc) ->
  doc["tags"] |> contains("delta")
end)
```